# #include boost without using libs linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost, include

The problem: At the moment im compiling on Ubuntu but my server is running Fedora/Redhat. Ubunutu uses boost 1.42 and linux latest at this very moment is 1.41. So what i decided was to download the boost lib and put it in the folder of my workspace

Here is the directory structure

```
/workspace
    /myprogram
        /src
            /main.cpp
        /Debug
            /main
    /boost_1_42_0
        /downloaded from boost.com
```

In my main.cpp, i have this code

```
#include "../../boost_1_42_0/boost/regex.hpp"
```

Is this even posible or am i barking up the wrong tree. I have tried to compile it but it failed (ofcourse) with 13 errors

If i missed some information please ask for it, il try providing it

**Make File (My Program is called vlogd)**

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include src/class/vException/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/row/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/query_results/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/query/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/fields/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/exceptions/subdir.mk
-include src/class/mysqlcppapi/datetime/subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: vlogd

# Tool invocations
vlogd: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -L/usr/lib64/mysql -L../../boost_1_42_0/lib/ -o"vlogd" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

#     Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) vlogd
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

**Object File**

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

USER_OBJS :=

LIBS := -lmysqlclient -lboost_regex
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to include using full path, if you use `gcc` just specify the correct include path and link path

```
gcc -I../../boost_1_42_0/ myprogram.cpp -L../../boost_1_42_0/lib -lboostXYZ
```

Thus, all `#include <boost/...>` headers and libs will be first searched in your local boost.

**Edit**
Following the question in the comment.

By default -l will search for `.so` libraries. So if boost is built with e.g. `libboost_regex.so` and `liboost_regex.a`, then by default you will link to the `.so`. If you're linked to `.so`, on the working server you need to have correct versions of these libraries (several boost versions can be installed).

If you want to link implicitly to the static versions, either use the full path

```
gcc .... ../../boost_1_42_0/lib/libboost_regex.a
```

or

```
gcc ... -Wl,-Bstatic -L../../boost_1_42_0/lib -lboost_regex -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

or (in newer versions of `ld`)

```
gcc ... -L../../boost_1_42_0/lib -l:libboost_regex.a
```

Having the binary with `ldd` command you may see its shared library dependencies and check if boost ones are among them

```
ldd ./yourapp
```

Comment: Would i also have to copy the boost files on my working server. Or will they be compiled in my program?

Comment: im using g++, Should i copy and paste the makefile eclipse makes for me

Comment: Most of the Boost libraries are headers only. As such, they'll be compiled into your program so there is no need to copy the Boost files to the target machine.

Comment: If the boost libraries you use are header only ten you do not need to copy anything after the compile

Comment: @Angel.King.47 see my edit following the question about copying boost to the working server.

Comment: Well following your concept, it semi works. I right clicked properties and went to settings Added -L library as `../../boost_1_42_0/boost/` and added -l `boost_regex` changed my #include <boost/regex.hpp> the program compiled. But still when i copy it over, it gives the same error, older version of boost

Comment: Please bear in mind im not compiling on my server, im compiling on ubuntu and copying the .exe over

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hs5a4eF2 @Dmitry Sry for being really lost im really new to gcc compilers. Thats what microsoft does to you unfortunatly

Comment: @Angel.King.47 search the included files and find where LIBS is defined, I can't see it in the makefile itself

Comment: yes, it's set -lboost_regex there, try on of the mentioned ways to link it statically. Also ../../boost_1_42_0_/lib was given as an example, you have to find where the built libraries actually are and use this path.

Comment: Im sort of on the right track. Thanks for your help. I think my -L Path is wrong cause i cant find them in the downloaded copy. But there is alot of folders so ima go troll through them.

Comment: ok so can i not use the files that are already in the `/usr/lib64` rather than using an external source that i have downloaded. To be compiled with the program

Answer (score 1):

I nice way to build boost libraries in your apps is to build your apps with bjam (with all its cross-platform friendliness)

I solve your problem like so - you can look here general documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/index.html

In my jamroot.jam (at the base of my project) - your /workspace folder- I have

```
#Name this location $(TOP),
path-constant TOP : . ;
## The location of the boost library
path-constant BOOST_BASE : ($TOP)/boost_1_42_0 ;  

#Define an alias to the regex libray
alias regex-library     
      : $(BOOST_BASE)/libs/regex/build//boost_regex
      : <include>$(BOOST_BASE) ;


# build your project file
build-project ./myprogram/build ;
```

Then in the myprogram/build directory I have a file called Jamfile.v2

```
project myprogram
  : source-location ../src  #your src directory
  : requirements <include>../src #your headerfiles can be in a different place if you wish 
             <warnings>all 
  : default-build   <threading>multi # for example
  : build-dir $(TOP)/build #where you want your object files put
;

exe myprogram   : main.cpp  
                 $(TOP)//regex-library # bjam should sort out the rest
         :
     <include> # any other includes
    ; 

alias install : install-bin ; 
# where you want your program installed
install install-bin : myprogram : <location>$(TOP)/bin ;
```

Hope this helps.  I have copied this out of my files so hopefully they should work - however there is a chance I made a mistake when putting your directory structure into them.  Let me know if it doesn't work.

The advantage of this system is that you actually build the library - so all compiler flags will be correct.  Also, if you upgrade the library, you should just need to change the BOOST_BASE flag.  Also, the build should work on windows and linux without any modification....

All the best,

Tom